# Running a VBS script elevated to get remote computer serial number

Tags: vbscript, permissions

Ok, I have an error someplace in here, but not sure where.  I am NOT a coder by any means, this is something I have put together from a couple of different sources.  This code works, however it seems to run once as a normal user and once at elevated permissions...  I just need it to run just once at elevated permissions.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
WScript.ScriptFullName & """" &_
" RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
End if
On Error Resume Next
Dim System
if Wscript.Arguments.Count >0 then
sSystem=Wscript.Arguments(0)
end if
ComputerName = InputBox("Enter the name of the computer you wish to query")
winmgmt1 = "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//"& ComputerName &""
Set SNSet = GetObject( winmgmt1 ).InstancesOf ("Win32_BIOS")
for each SN in SNSet
MsgBox "The serial number for the specified computer is: " & SN.SerialNumber
next
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the part that re-runs your script with elevated privileges by using the [`Shell.ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method with the `"runas"` verb:

```vbs
If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
WScript.ScriptFullName & """" &_
" RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
End if
```

Re-running the script with the additional parameter `RunAsAdministrator` makes sure that the re-run script skips the above part (since `WScript.Arguments.Length` is greater than 0 due to that parameter) and goes directly to the "worker" code.

However, the above code snippet doesn't exit after re-running the script, so both the elevated *and* the original invocation are executing the worker code.

Add a `WScript.Quit` statement to your code to make the original invocation exit right after re-running itself with elevated permissions and the issue will disappear:

```vbs
If WScript.Arguments.Length = 0 Then
  Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", _
    """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit 0
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

that's all (for remote computer):

```
ComputerName = InputBox("Enter the name of the computer you wish to query")
winmgmt1 = "winmgmts:(impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//"& ComputerName &"\root\cimv2")
Set SNSet = winmgmt1.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_BIOS")
for each SN in SNSet
MsgBox "The serial number for the specified computer is: " & SN.SerialNumber
next
```